# A recursive must resolve to type but I don't know how to structure it?

Tags: java, if-statement, recursion, while-loop

```
public static Directory makePath(Directory parent, String[] path) {
    // While path has more than one item in it, recurse
    if (path.length > 1) {
        System.out.println(parent + "1");
        // If dir exists, go into the next level
        if (parent.isChildDirectory(path[0])) {
            String[] newPath = Arrays.copyOfRange(path, 1, path.length);
            Directory newParent = parent.getChildDirectory(path[0]);
            FileSystem.makePath(newParent, newPath);
        }
        // If dir does not exist, create it and then go into the next level
        else {
            parent.addDirectory(path[0]);
            String[] newPath = Arrays.copyOfRange(path, 1, path.length);
            Directory newParent = parent.getChildDirectory(path[0]);
            FileSystem.makePath(newParent, newPath);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(parent + "2");
        // If dir exists, go into the next level
        if (parent.isChildDirectory(path[0])) {
            return parent.getChildDirectory(path[0]);
        }
        // If dir does not exist, create it and then go into the next level
        else {
            parent.addDirectory(path[0]);
            return parent.getChildDirectory(path[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Java won't compile this method right now because in the first if section, the results don't return Directory objects.
I had the if/else be while (path.length >1) before, but then it just goes into infinite loop.. Can someone help me with an alternative structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *suspect* you just want to return the results of the recursive calls. So turn these calls:

```
FileSystem.makePath(newParent, newPath);
```

into

```
return FileSystem.makePath(newParent, newPath);
```

Although I think it's worth noting that you have a lot of duplicated code here - so this:

```
if (parent.isChildDirectory(path[0])) {
    String[] newPath = Arrays.copyOfRange(path, 1, path.length);
    Directory newParent = parent.getChildDirectory(path[0]);
    return FileSystem.makePath(newParent, newPath);
}
// If dir does not exist, create it and then go into the next level
else {
    parent.addDirectory(path[0]);
    String[] newPath = Arrays.copyOfRange(path, 1, path.length);
    Directory newParent = parent.getChildDirectory(path[0]);
    return FileSystem.makePath(newParent, newPath);
}
```

could just be:

```
if (!parent.isChildDirectory(path[0])) {
    parent.addDirectory(path[0]);
}
String[] newPath = Arrays.copyOfRange(path, 1, path.length);
Directory newParent = parent.getChildDirectory(path[0]);
return FileSystem.makePath(newParent, newPath);
```

Try to isolate *just* the behaviour which is conditional, and only include that in your `if` body.